# How to build up a dynamic OR query in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to dynamically create a where clause with link. 
Now, creating something like `SELECT Product WHERE x = 123 AND y = 349 AND w = 948` is no problem. I'm just adding extra Where filters. 
`products = products.Where(product => product.Property == 123);`

But now i have an unknown number of values that should be tested with an OR operator. The SQL Should be like `SELECT Product WHERE x = 123 OR x = 499 OR x = 998 .. and n more OR's`

Comment: I would want my SQL for the above query to be `SELECT Product WHERE x IN(123, 499, 998)`

Comment: Yes you are right, that SQL describes it a bit better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a list of numbers to check and do something like the following:

```
var idsToCheck = new List<int>{123, 789, 654}; //Build from dynamic list
products = products.Where(x => idsToCheck.Contains(x.Id));
```

The above can be duplicated for v and w if required

```
var idsToCheck = new List<int>{123, 789, 654}; //Build from dynamic list
products = products.Where(x => idsToCheck.Contains(x.Id));

var propertyToCheck = new List<int>{123, 789, 654};//Build from dynamic list
products = products.Where(x => propertyToCheck.Contains(x.Property));

var numberToCheck = new List<int>{123, 789, 654};
products = products.Where(x => numberToCheck.Contains(x.Number));
```

If your values to check are already being passed in as enumerables then you don't need to build your xxxToCheck collections. You can simply do the `.Contains` against the originals

Answer (score 0):

You can use contains on a list or just have the equation like so:

```
  products.Where(product => (product.Property == 123) || (product.Property == 499) || (product.Property == 998));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compose an OR query from multiple where clauses you really need to compose the predicates in the where clauses instead. Afterall, chaining where clauses would be an AND.

So, if you have the following predicates:

```
Func<Product, bool> w1 = p => p.x == 123;
Func<Product, bool> w2 = p => p.y == 349;
Func<Product, bool> w3 = p => p.w == 948;
Func<Product, bool> w4 = p => p.Property == 123;
Func<Product, bool> w5 = p => p.x == 499;
Func<Product, bool> w6 = p => p.x == 998;
```

You can define the following extension method to OR them:

```
public static Func<T, bool> Or<T>(this Func<T, bool> @this, Func<T, bool> that)
{
    return t => @this(t) || that(t);
}
```

Now you could write:

```
var products1 = products.Where(w1.Or(w5).Or(w6));

var products2 = products.Where(
    ((Func<Product, bool>)(p => p.x == 123))
        .Or(p => p.y == 349)
        .Or(p => p.Property == 123));
```

If you want to work with lists of clauses then add this extension method:

```
public static Func<T, bool> Or<T>(this IEnumerable<Func<T, bool>> @this)
{
    return @this.Aggregate((Func<T, bool>)(t => true), (a, t) => a.Or(t));
}
```

Now you can write:

```
var predicates = new List<Func<Product, bool>>()
{
    p => p.x == 123,
    p => p.w == 948,
    p => p.Property == 123,
    p => p.x == 998,
};

var products3 = products.Where(predicates.Or());
```

If you're writing this against an `IQueryable<T>` provider then you need to work with `Expression<Func<Product, bool>>` and not just `Func<Product, bool>`.

Then you need these extension methods:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(
    this Expression<Func<T, bool>> @this,
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> that)
{
    var param =
        Expression
            .Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
    var body =
        Expression
            .Or(
                Expression
                    .Invoke(@this, param),
                Expression
                    .Invoke(that, param));
    return
        Expression
            .Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
}

public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(
    this IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> @this)
{
    return @this.Aggregate((Expression<Func<T, bool>>)(t => true), (a, t) => a.Or(t));
}
```

The calling code still works the same:

```
var predicatesX = new List<Expression<Func<Product, bool>>>()
{
    p => p.x == 123,
    p => p.w == 948,
    p => p.Property == 123,
    p => p.x == 998,
};

var products3X = products.Where(predicatesX.Or());
```

Is this what you were looking for?